# R, install package from source vs. use install.package() and CRAN mirror

Tags: r, linux

The answers to this question: [Determine if R package is available on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43297797/determine-if-r-package-is-available-on-linux) mention installing R packages from source, specifically in the context of R running on linux.  For instance, pages such as [this](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/debian/) and [this](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/) give specific instructions for installing packages on various linux systems, and StackOverflow questions such as: [How do I install an R package from source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474081/how-do-i-install-an-r-package-from-source) address the issue more generally.  Finally, the answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43298332/3541976) SO question mentions that unix users tend to install packages from source.

I've used R on my university's CentOS linux server a decent bit and have always just added new packages using `install.packages()` from within R and specifying a CRAN repository.  This generally works fine, though I do notice that it often takes far longer than when installing packages on my personal computer.

What would be the reason to:

(a) Download the .tar.gz file and specify its path via the `path` argument in `install.packages()` and/or

(b) Install the package directly from a command line call, as specified, for instance, [here](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/debian/), [here](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43298332/3541976)

as opposed to just using `install.package()` from within R and specifying a given online repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You hit an important overall question -- "should I install from a binary repository (where available) or should I install from source" -- but I fear you are a little confused about other aspects:

- You rightly point to the Debian and Ubuntu READMEs. Ubuntu is particularly useful as Michael's (off-CRAN) PPA repos provide about 3200 package that are directly installable as binaries. Nothing is faster.
- But that is for Ubuntu and you run CentOS. No soup for you.
- So source installation it is.
- And source installation *is always from a .tar.gz* and the various methods you list (command-line, `install.packages()`, ...) and alternative (Package tab in RStudio, say) are *all equivalent* as the all call the same underlying function.

It is really just different veneer for convenience.

Comment: Got it, this is very helpful. My particular context is that I'm about to set up my own Ubuntu server, so that is helpful to know about the Ubuntu-specific aspect.  But, is it correct that whether I use those Ubuntu specific repos, or the general source install, the actual function of my packages will be the same, so it's just a matter of speed and convenience?

Comment: No there is a difference between pre-built (ie .deb) and from source. I have another answer or two here on the site; there is also prior r-sig-debian discussion.  Try some googling to unearth it, I do not have the links handy right now.

Comment: Got it, thanks.  The answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9644699/difference-between-installing-a-package-from-source-and-from-compiled-binary) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170043/r-apt-get-install-r-cran-foo-vs-install-packagesfoo) were quite helpful.